# batch file/cmd for r scripts

Tags: r, cmd

I found out that I can run the R scripts in cmd like this

```
Rscript.exe -e "1+1"

[1] 2
```

But I know how can I work only with simple scripts. Once I try to run something bit complicated like this

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\i386\Rscript.exe" -e "Map(source, list.files(path="//server/Reports/scripts/R/", pattern="R$", full.names = T)) ff_bank_transfers(start_date <- as.Date("2018-01-01"), end_date <- Sys.Date())"
pause
```

I still getting some errors

```
Error: unnexpected '/' in "Map(source, list.files(path=/"
Execution halted
```

I believe that this is because some escape character that is not valid for cmd/R but I can´t find which one.

Comment: The escape character is backslash, not forward slash. I'm guessing your use of quotes is incorrect. You cannot use double quotes inside double quotes without an escape. You may also need `shQuote`.

Comment: Does R support remote file listings URIs like what you have? I've not seen `list.files` take as an argument anything other than an absolute or relative path on the local machine. Your `//server/Reports/scripts/R` looks like you're expecting to pull from a remote host named `server`. Am I missing something?